# ERROR while installing scikit-image in raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, scikit-learn

While installing scikit-image library in raspberry pi 3 using pip, it says "Collecting dask[array]>=1.0.0(from scikit-image)" 
and then shows this error
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dask[array]>=1.0.0 (from scikit-image) (from versions: 0.7.4.linux-x86_64, 0.7.5.linux-x86_64, 0.7.6.linux-x86_64, 0.8.1.macosx-10.5-x86_64, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.4, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.12.0, 0.13.0rc1, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 0.14.3, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.15.3, 0.15.4, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.17.2, 0.17.3, 0.17.4, 0.17.5, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.18.2)
No matching distribution found for dask[array]>=1.0.0 (from scikit-image)

Please someone help me.

Comment: Can you show me which command are you trying to use to install?

Comment: pip install scikit-learn

Comment: I tryied here and worked fine for me. Try install just the scikit-image: `pip install scikit-image`.

Comment: I used that also but it's not working.

Comment: which raspbian version are you using?

Comment: raspbian jessie

Comment: Did you try change the version?

Comment: can you tell your raspbean version

Comment: Mine is Stretch

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on a ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Dask 1.0.0 requires at least python 3.5. So you need to upgrade your python installation or try installing an older version of scikit-image using:

```
pip install scikit-image==<version-number>
```

for instance version 0.13.0 seems to work